# How to categorise resultset from Stored Procedure in Asp.Net Core Razor pages for rendering graphs using chartjs

Tags: asp.net-core, dynamic, chart.js, razor-pages

I have a stored procedure as shown below,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_DistinctFunction]
                 @CustomerName NVARCHAR(MAX)                                                    
                 AS
BEGIN
                 SET NOCOUNT ON;
                 SELECT [function]as FuncName, EmployeeGroup as EmpGrp, Count(BadgeNo) as EmpCount
                 FROM EmployeeData
                 WHERE CustomerName = @CustomerName  Group By [function], EmployeeGroup
END
GO
```

The result set will be like ,
[image]

I want to plot a graph with this resultset. For that i am using Chartjs.
First i want a graph for each Employee Group with function as bar.Please refer to the pic below

[image]

Please advise how to dynamically generate graph for this?

Answer (score 0):

We can try to use the SqlDependency's OnChange event to detect the database updated and use SignalR to update the Chartjs graph.

You can [check thread first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1159844/implementing-signalr-in-asp-net-core-web-app-(mvc)), and we can change the `commandText` as we needed. If the data changed, you can query the database views.

And for front end, we can check [this official doc](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html) to update the graph.